# How to move from Django to REST-API/Thin Client?

Tags: javascript, python, rest

We are thinking to move away from Django and separate the backend and frontend.
The backend is straight forward as I have done it plenty of times by exposing it as a `Python RESTful API`.

Whats new to me is the thin client part.

Theoretically I could just write `HTML` and plain `javascript` to talk to the API.

Is there a `macro-framework` that would help me to achieve that? Beside `AngularJS`, what other thin client frameworks could I utilise without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: if the question isn't clear, please let me know to improve it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of alternatives out there.  You really have to get your hand dirty to find the solution that suit you.

On one end, you have [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) that is famous for how small the code base is but you need to add core components such template engine using [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) or similar.  On the other end, you have full fledge framework such as [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and [ReactJS](http://facebook.github.io/react/).

Here are some material to get you started:

- [Choosing a JavaScript MVC Framework](http://www.funnyant.com/choosing-javascript-mvc-framework/)
- [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/)

TodoMVC is specially interesting as it implement the same app in multiple frameworks so you have a comparison base.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you might be looking for something like jQuery. It's a subtle JS framework that will make it easier to talk to your Django API, especially using Ajax and JSON.